# Android - Set the space between GridLayout children programatically?

Tags: android, width, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout that gets created in XML, but the children/icons are added at runtime. For some reason the cells get squashed together, so how can I set the space between cells at runtime?

I'm pretty much adding the icons to the GridLayout using `grid.addView(icon)` in an OnLongClickListener from a button.

This is what I get:

[image: Stuff]

And yes, I'm making a launcher.

Any solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a 16 column grid. In the first (or last) row is a dummy row (below only the first column is included).

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="16" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_id_col0"
        android:text="@string/grid_col0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="6"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="camera" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_column="10"
        android:layout_columnSpan="16"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="clock" />

</GridLayout>
```

At run time you can specify the width of the columns.

```
    TextView colTv = (TextView) inRootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_id_col0);
    colTv.setWidth(colWidth);
    colTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

The colWidth is derived from the device width divided by the number of columns.
The space between the two images is there if you leave some columns without any content. In the example above columns 6 to 9 for row 1 do not have content.